# Kimball Bridge Tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, dimensional-modeling

I'm attempting to create a bridge table in a PostgreSQL database following the Kimball Data Warehouse Toolkit approach mentioned [here](http://www.kimballgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Building-the-Hierarchy-Bridge-Table.pdf) so that I can support hierarchies of indeterminate depth.

The basic idea is that if you have a tree hierarchy of nodes, you want a table that has a row for every possible path in the tree.

To start, you create the table of parent-child relationships like so:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

Create table COMPANY (
COMPANY_KEY INTEGER NOT NULL,
COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR,
PARENT_KEY INTEGER);

INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (100,'MICROSOFT',NULL);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (101,'SOFTWARE',100);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (102,'CONSULTING',101);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (103,'PRODUCTS',101);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (104,'OFFICE',103);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (105,'VISIO',104);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (106,'VISIO EUROPE',105);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (107,'BACK OFFICE',103);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (108,'SQL SERVER',107);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (109,'OLAP SERVICES',108);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (110,'DTS',108);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (111,'REPOSITORY',108);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (112,'DEVELOPER TOOLS',103);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (113,'WINDOWS',103);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (114,'ENTERTAINMENT',103);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (115,'GAMES',114);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (116,'MULTIMEDIA',114);
INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (117,'EDUCATION',101);

END TRANSACTION;
```

From the document above, they recommend using the following code to build out the bridge table from the above-created table:

```
WITH REC (root_id, level, company_key, parent_key, company_name, unparsed_company_name)
AS (
    SELECT company_key, 
        1,
        company_key, 
        parent_key, 
        company_name, 
        CAST(company_name AS VARCHAR(250))
    FROM company
    WHERE parent_key IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        rec.root_id,
        rec.level + 1, 
        rec_plus1.company_key, 
        rec_plus1.parent_key, 
        rec_plus1.company_name, 
        TRIM(rec.unparsed_company_name)||'>'||TRIM(rec_plus1.company_name)
    FROM company AS rec_plus1, rec
    WHERE rec.company_key = rec_plus1.parent_key
)
SELECT 
    company_key,
    parent_key,
    company_name,
    root_id,
    level AS depth_from_parent,
    COALESCE((SELECT 'N' FROM company s2 WHERE s1.company_key = s2.parent_key FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY), 'Y') AS lowest_flag,
    (SELECT (CASE WHEN MAX (s2.level) = s1.level THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) FROM rec s2 WHERE s1.root_id = s2.company_key) AS top_most_flag,
    REPEAT('', level*5)||level||'-'||company_name AS company_logical_tree,
    unparsed_company_name FROM rec s1;
```

I tried converting the above into PostgreSQL-specific code as follows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE company_bridge AS
WITH RECURSIVE rec (root_id, level, company_key, parent_key, company_name, unparsed_company_name)
AS (
    SELECT company_key::integer, 
        1, 
        company_key::integer, 
        parent_key::integer, 
        company_name::varchar, 
        company_name::varchar
    FROM company
    WHERE parent_key IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        rec.root_id,
        rec.level + 1, 
        rec_plus1.company_key, 
        rec_plus1.parent_key, 
        rec_plus1.company_name, 
        (TRIM(rec.unparsed_company_name)||'>'||TRIM(rec_plus1.company_name))::varchar
    FROM company AS rec_plus1, rec
    WHERE rec.company_key = rec_plus1.parent_key
)
SELECT 
    company_key,
    parent_key,
    company_name,
    root_id,
    level AS depth_from_parent,
    COALESCE((SELECT 'N'::varchar FROM company AS s2 WHERE s1.company_key = s2.parent_key FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY), 'Y'::varchar) AS lowest_flag,
    (SELECT (CASE WHEN MAX (s2.level) = s1.level THEN 'Y'::varchar ELSE 'N'::varchar END) FROM rec AS s2 WHERE s1.root_id = s2.company_key) AS top_most_flag,
    REPEAT('', level*5)||level||'-'||company_name AS company_logical_tree,
    unparsed_company_name FROM rec AS s1;
ALTER TABLE company_bridge ADD PRIMARY KEY (company_key);

END TRANSACTION;
```

This produces this output, however, which only has rows from each parent to their immediate children:

[image: Bridge Table Result]

What I need is a row for each parent node to every node it has below it. To help visualize this, here's the above table drawn as a tree diagram:

[image: Tree Diagram]

Starting with the top node, 100, it should have a row for: 100-100 (itself), 100->101, 100->102, 100->103 ... all the way to 100->117 - that is, every node in the tree. The next node 101, should have the same for each node below it, including itself: 101->101, 101->102 ... 101->117. A node further down the tree, like 108, would just have: 108->108, 108->109, 108->110 and 108->111.

I'm just getting used to using recursion in Postgres so I'm having a difficult time diagnosing what the problem may be. Any ideas?

Comment: Please be more specific. If you want all possible path just remove `WHERE ... IS NULL`. **[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bdb7f/1/0)**. The question is how do you want calcualte levels. Do you want them from each parent as 1 or do you want levels from most common ancestor? Check [demo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bdb7f/2/0). `Office` starts from level 1 or it should start from `4`?

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this. I've updated the above to clarify what I'm trying to get, as unfortunately the two demos you put together aren't quite it.

Comment: What is wrong with first demo? top_most_flag? That's is the only difference I could find from Kimball (as he is not assigning Y to parent of the subtree, eg. "where root_id = company_key and root_id != 'realroot'). And demo is containing 'null' for top most root, that is only difference I could find, and I am wondering how they would impact your use case.